# How to reduce the rate of false positive and false negative in OpenCV person detection?

Tags: java, opencv

I'm trying to detect the number of persons that appear in a Video and output a video where the detected persons have a rectangle drawn around them.
However I am experiencing a very high rate of false negative (persons without no ractangle) and false positive (rectangle drawn on the void).
I have the same problem with the faces detection.

[False negative example](http://aseddiki.vvv.enseirb.fr/projet_S9/false_negative.png)

[False positive example](http://aseddiki.vvv.enseirb.fr/projet_S9/false_positive.png)

Here are the functions I run to get the persons detected (in Java)

```
final Size winStride = new Size(8, 8);
final Size padding = new Size(32, 32);

// Persons detection
hog.detectMultiScale(frame, outputPersons, outputWeights, 0.0, winStride, padding, 1.05, 2.0, false);

// Faces detection
faceDetector.detectMultiScale(frame, outputFaces);
```

Comment: There is no universal way to "make your algorithm better". You may try play with the thresholds or change the preprocessing steps or may be replace the algorithm with another one.